# Jenkins Agents fail to connect after update from Version 2.7.2 to 2.107.2

Tags: jenkins, jnlp

I recently updated the jenkins server from version 2.7.2 to 2.107.2 on Windows Server Standard 2016 (both server and agent). After that everything was still working until I restarted one of the agents. The jenkins Windows Service on the agent keeps crashing and reports the following in the error log file:

```
Mai 07, 2018 5:59:34 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main createEngine
INFO: Setting up slave: dsvjenkins4
Mai 07, 2018 5:59:34 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener <init>
INFO: Jenkins agent is running in headless mode.
Mai 07, 2018 5:59:34 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Locating server among [https://dsvjenkins1/]
Mai 07, 2018 5:59:34 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Handshaking
Mai 07, 2018 5:59:34 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to dsvjenkins1:16923
Mai 07, 2018 5:59:34 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Trying protocol: JNLP3-connect
Mai 07, 2018 5:59:34 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Server didn't accept the handshake: Disabled protocol:Protocol:JNLP3-connect
Mai 07, 2018 5:59:34 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to dsvjenkins1:16923
Mai 07, 2018 5:59:34 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Trying protocol: JNLP2-connect
Mai 07, 2018 5:59:34 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Server didn't accept the handshake: Disabled protocol:Protocol:JNLP2-connect
Mai 07, 2018 5:59:34 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to dsvjenkins1:16923
Mai 07, 2018 5:59:34 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Trying protocol: JNLP-connect
Mai 07, 2018 5:59:34 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Server didn't accept the handshake: Disabled protocol:Protocol:JNLP-connect
Mai 07, 2018 5:59:34 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to dsvjenkins1:16923
Mai 07, 2018 5:59:34 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener error
SEVERE: The server rejected the connection: None of the protocols were accepted
java.lang.Exception: The server rejected the connection: None of the protocols were accepted
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.onConnectionRejected(Engine.java:335)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:307)
```

I tried uninstalling and installing the agent service by connecting to the new jenkins server. It does start with Java Web Start. But I need to get it running as a windows service.
I did restart the agent after the reinstalling the agent as a service.
Later I found out that it was not one agent. All agents are affected once they are rebooted.

What could I do to resolve this?

**[Update]**
Jenkins 2.107.2 guided me throught some improvements after the installation. One of them was to disable insecure JNLP protocols. JNLP1, JNLP2 and JNLP3 were disabled. Since the handshaking with the agents had already happened, the communication between server and agent would still be based on one of these disabled protocols until the agent was restarted.
I ended up reenabling all the protocols and then disabled one by one to find out what is the most secure setting that still works. Having JNLP3 and JNLP4 enabled while JNLP1 and JNLP2 are diabled still works.
 That leads me to a follow up question: How can I get the communication working between master and agent with the JNLP4 protocol only?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by redownloading the `agent.jar` file from the Jenkins server, then restarting the slave.  Example:

```
$ wget http://[servername:port]/jenkins/jnlpJars/agent.jar

$ java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://[servername:port]/jenkins/computer/[slave-name]/slave-agent.jnlp
```

This allowed the Jenkins slave to start up using JNLP4.

Answer (score 0):

FYI in case it helps any – I just had to go through a big diag effort on my site with a bunch of windows JNLP agents that stopped working sometime in past few days with the same above failures/errors.

After a long set of rabbit trails - what I found in my case – the problem wound up being reverse DNS resolution stopped working (unrelated local problem – "It's always DNS", right?) - but that inability to reverse resolve the connecting client (windows box) was causing the JNLP server side to drop the connection.

Just wanted to add this here in case it helps anyone else with future similar issues if it happens to be related.